# How to make an arrow triangle in CSS with smooth sides?

Tags: css

I want to ask how can i create a css arrow triangle with smooth sides i.e. no cut in the side of arrow without using any image? I have already tried the tutorial -

[http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/][1]

```css
.arrow_up
    {
     width: 0; 
     height: 0; 
     border-left: 10px solid transparent;
     border-right: 10px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 10px solid black;
     position:absolute;
     top:75px;
     left:250px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="arrow_up"></div>
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry, the issue was found only in some older version of Firefox.

Comment: It works fine without the notch: http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/qLAg4/

Comment: oh dear you have not read my question carefully. You have shown me what i have already. You must have an eye to catch the bug. You demo also has that cut on right side. Please check again.

Comment: @Sachin the demo **works OK on my side**, at least it might not work on your side. There is nothing wrong with the code. You can have some solution to solve it **but** the cause of your problem is still a secret. I've tested the demo on all the latest versions of all the major browsers IE, Chrome, Opera, FireFox and even Maxthon. All render the triangle OK. It's just not OK **on your side**. Please remember that. Maybe you're using some old version of some browser or there is something wrong with your screen/graphics/ ... related settings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a pseudo element and rotate it:
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qLAg4/1/)**

---

CSS:

```
.arrow_up
{
    width: 100px; 
    height: 50px; 
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    left:250px;
    overflow:hidden;/* hide part of the pseudo overflowing*/
}
.arrow_up:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:100%;/* it will draw a square , change this value for other degrees angles*/
    transform:rotate(45deg);/* we'll see a corner */
    background:black;
    top:20px;/* tune this according to size of parent or size to be seen */
}
```

***Do not forget to add vendor-prefix or use a script that adds them automaticly.***

---

The use o a pseudo element allows to add content in the box : ie. http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gdoGA

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can possibly think of is that you have another element on the page which is slightly overlapping onto the arrow as when tested it works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/qLAg4/

```
.arrow_up {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    left: 250px;
}
```

It could be something to do with your browser as well though

Comment: Yes its due to browser. The image i uploaded to show you is taken from firefox. Firefox is showing the cut. When i saw it in chrome then it was fine. So how can i make it equal in both browsers?